# Qt gSoap server VS Jax-WS need sugesstions

Tags: java, web-services, qt, jax-ws, gsoap

My Company is going to start new project this year which need to archive web services on it way and I need to make decision on some technical things. After some research on web I thought that Qt and gsoap also can be candidate for the job we want to be done.
We were working long time with Java and C# based web service but now we need to solve two problems mentioned below:

1. Web service need to be extremaly fast
2. Easy adding service mwthods to it as we go

To be honest I think that we will not have much work in this side just several service methods to analyze and store data in database.

Thats why, as performance is very important for us we think that Qt + gSoap is option to go with.

It will be very nice to know what to use Qt/gSoap/C++ or Java/Jax-Ws taking in consideration two options listed above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a performance benchmark available?

Comment: un no
Thats why I posted question.
If someone knows where to get it or has tested it will be nice to have:)

Comment: If your project is 'large enough' you may consider to run your own benchmark...